# Issue Google Shopping Index Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, database

**Trying to setup Google Merchant from Magento version 2.3.3**

Now when done and I run:

**php bin/magento indexer:reindex scconnector_google_feed**

I get an error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'catalog_product_entity.aw_gc_email_templates' in 'field list',

Which is referring to our `AheadWorks Gift Card` extension. However, I can not change scope as it is greyed out and not sure how now to solve this.

The error causes the index not to run properly.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

**Thanks.**

Comment: do you have this column? `aw_gc_email_templates`

Comment: No, should we try to just reinstall the extension you think?

Comment: My bad, we have it as an product attribute with that code

Comment: So let me make it complete. This is full error on ssh

Comment: Google Product Feed indexer process unknown error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'catalog_product_entity.aw_gc_email_templates' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id`, `catalog_product_entity`.`type_id`, `catalog_product_entity`.`sku , `catalog_product_entity`.`required_options`, `catalog_product_entity`.`has_options`,catalog_product_entity`.`mst_search_weight`, `catalog_product_entity`.`aw_gc_email_templates`, `catalog_product_entity`.`aw_gc_amounts`, `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity`

Comment: In  catalog_product_entity of database the aw attributes are missing.